# How can I set up a reverse osmosis water system to use a pressure tank?

Tags: water-resources

Most home reverse osmosis water systems use a low pressure bladder type tank that has 5-10 PSI. That way the back pressure on the RO system is not too high.

I want to use a glass-lined tank of the type used for people with well water and have it pressurized to a faucet-type pressure of around 30 PSI. The only way I can figure out how to do this is to have two tanks, one unpressurized and the other pressurized. So, the RO system would drip water into the unpressurized tank. Then a pump would draw water out of the unpressurized tank and force it into the pressure tank.

Is this the only way to do this, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Short answer - yep, two tanks. Longer answer - it depends on what you are starting with and the size system you are considering. If you have a 60 gal/hr seawater desalinator that can run up to 900 psi or so, it really won't care too much about a 30 psi pressure tank, the production may drop a few percent as the pressure nears cutout. If you are starting with a little system designed for brackish water operating at 200 psi, you're pretty much stuck.